# How to transform added circles correctly?

Tags: d3.js

Why, after increasing the zoom reduction is not correctly recalculated coordinates. If you initially do not zoom, then the points are scaled correctly, even at zoom. But if you play, then everything falls off. Tell me how to transform the circles? [See example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZdGeqE).

```js
function getCorrectCoordinate(){

  const TRANSLATE = 53; 

  default_point.x = d3.event.clientX,
  default_point.y = d3.event.clientY;

  let path_point = default_point.matrixTransform(path.node().getScreenCTM().inverse());

  path_point = closestPoint(path, [path_point.x, path_point.y]);

  default_point.x = path_point[0];
  default_point.y = path_point[1];

  let correct_coordinate = default_point.matrixTransform(path.node().getScreenCTM());

  correct_coordinate.x = Math.round(correct_coordinate.x - position_svg.x - TRANSLATE);
  correct_coordinate.y = Math.round(correct_coordinate.y - position_svg.y - TRANSLATE);
  correct_coordinate.distance = path_point.distance;

  return correct_coordinate;
}
```

Comment: Everything seems ok to me. Behaved the same way after multiple zooms as it did initially.

Comment: @pmkro If you place circles without zooming they are fine. If you move one and then place circle after they move weirdly

Comment: an other problem that you might have is, if there is scroll, the circle hover appear as the place as there isn't any scroll (reduce the size of the screen, scroll and then try to place a cricle to reproduce)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you add the new circles without transform value, so when you zoom, you apply the transform to the old circle (which behave well) but also to the new one which aren't placed as the first one.

[image]

As you can see on the screenshot, the first cicle has a transform value but not the second one.

But if you add the transform value it will completly change the position of the circle where you click, so you must have to calcul the coordinate in th original plan from the translated plan you currently have.

Basically: `cx = mouseX - valud_of_translateX`, same for cy.

Here it would be `cx = 184.7975... - 81.3308...`

Comment: Updated Codepen. There is a solution.

Comment: @doox911 what do you mean? I don't understand your comment sorry